# Pycharm does not locate my python installation and keeps generating its own python

Tags: python, pycharm

I have Python 3.7 installed and it's on my PATH. (Windows 10) 
When I login to Python from Command line it logs in to Python and I have access to all my libraries.
When I use Pycharm however, each project generates its own Python.exe which requires installing all the required packages.
In the project interpretor, I can see the Python instances of different projects but not my actually installed Python 3.7.
Question is: How can I direct my Pycharm project to my own installed Python with all packages installed?

Answer (score 1):

That is, in fact, a good thing. You don't want to litter your system-wide python with libs from different projects.

What you can do, though, is setup virtual environments to your specific needs. Go to your project settings and type `venv` in the search field. You will be presented with a screen where you can select which interpreter to use for this particular project.